# How to prevent systemd suspend from stopping any service with a dont-sleep.service

Tags: 16.04, suspend, systemd

I have a HTPC/NAS with 16.04.1 LTS, which I want to go into suspend mode after 15min of inactivity.
On the other hand I want to inhibit suspend mode if...

- ... I am logged in via ssh.
- ... pyLoad is downloading.
- ... there are active screen sessions.

I created a `dont-sleep.service` in `/etc/systemd/system/`. The service executes a `dont-sleep` script before *sleep.target*, which returns 1 if any of the points above are true.

So far this seems to work, however I noticed, while watching a video via sftp, that the connection seems to be interrupted every 15min.
`systemctl status dont-sleep.service` tells me, that this happens exactly whenever systemd tries to go into suspend, but is stopped by my `dont-sleep.service`.

So my assumptions is, that systemd stops some necessary services, before or while invoking my `dont-sleep` script and restarts them after my script returns 1.

How can I fix that?

#### systemctl status dont-sleep.service:

```
$ sudo systemctl status dont-sleep.service 
● dont-sleep.service - Inhibit suspend.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dont-sleep.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Di 2016-09-27 18:53:44 CEST; 28min ago
  Process: 10292 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dont-sleep (code=exited, status=1/FAILLURE)
 Main PID: 10292 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC systemd[1]: Starting Inhibit suspend....
Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC dont-sleep[10292]: Test for open ssh connections
Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC dont-sleep[10292]: Open connections found
Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC systemd[1]: dont-sleep.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC systemd[1]: Failed to start Inhibit suspend..
Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC systemd[1]: dont-sleep.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 27 18:53:44 HTPC systemd[1]: dont-sleep.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

#### dont-sleep.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Inhibit suspend.
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dont-sleep
User=xxx
Group=xxx

[Install]
RequiredBy=sleep.target
```

Comment: Very good question!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: @epsicot no, I dropped the subject while waiting on answers.
After reading the answer of Cloudranger, I assume it is not possible,
since the parallel execution is an intrinsic feature of systemd.
The only work-around I see is to implement my own auto-suspend service,
but I wanted to avoid reimplementing all the already built-in “user-is-active” functionality.

Comment: I just would like to comment that your dont-sleep.service helped me to create a service that advises my application that the system is going to sleep. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to prevent Ubuntu 16.04 from sleeping during a remote backup (rsync running over ssh using backuppc).  I have implemented your solution above and so far it seems to be working for me.

To answer your question, at the same time as the dont-sleep runs I see in syslog that NetworkManager disconnects the network then re-connects it (which in my case takes about 12 seconds).  As ssh is pretty robust and seems not to care about small network interruptions like that, this doesn't seem to hinder my backup, though it is clearly not ideal.

At the moment I assume the reason the network disconnects it is because all processes for sleeping are run in parallel, which is explained in the man pages for systemd-suspend:

> executables in this directory are executed in parallel, and execution
>   of the action is not continued until all executables have finished.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/systemd-suspend.service.8.html

If this is the case, then there would seem to be no hope to guarantee to be the first process and to stop the sleep actions before any other sleep processes have started to run (without modification to systemd to specifically support that at least).